# Vue3/pinia ref value inside defineStore is always undefined also with defaultValue

Tags: vuejs3, pinia

Is this intentional?

When I declare a ref with default value inside a pinia defineStore (and then return it) when I access it from a component is always undefined, until I perform operations on it.

The store:

```
import {defineStore} from "pinia";
import {ref} from "vue";

export const useSelection = defineStore("selection", () => {

    const contents = ref([]);

    return {
        contents
    };
});
```

The component:

```
<script>
import { defineComponent, computed } from "vue";
import { useSelection } from "../store/selection.js";

export default defineComponent({
    name: "Test",
    setup() {
        
        const selection = useSelection();
        
        const thereIsSelection = computed(() => {
            return selection.contents.value.length > 0;
        })

        return {
            thereIsSelection
        };
    },
});
</script>
```

With this code I always get
`Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')` as `selection.contents.value` is `undefined`

Is this normal? Best way to solve it? A computed instead of direct access to `selection.contents` that returns an array if `selection.contents` is `undefined`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do `return selection.contents.length > 0;` instead of `return selection.contents.value.length > 0;`

```js
const thereIsSelection = computed(() => {
  return selection.contents.length > 0;
});
```

`selection.contents` is the actual value you need, not a reference.

Answer (score 0):

**firstly**

`value` should be value**s** in

```
selection.contents.value.length
```

like this

```
selection.contents.values.length
```

**secondly**

for me, using `ref([])` was giving me this error

```
Uncaught TypeError: <my state>.<my array> is undefined
```

changing `ref([])` to `ref(new Array())` made the error go away